# Is there a PHP DocBlock I can use to denote a magic-method property added after instantiation?

Tags: php, templates, model-view-controller

I'm sending PHP objects to template files and would love to document at the top of my template file what properties of the object (using __get) are available and what they are and make them available for code-hinting.

Here's an example.

In my controller:

```
$obj = new Template("welcomePage");
$obj->title = "Welcome!";
$obj->render();
```

In my view / template:

```
<?php 
/** 
 *    @var       $obj           Template    The template data wrapper
 *    @property  $obj->title    string      The page header text
/* ?>
<h1><?php echo $obj->title; ?></h1>
```

Is there something similar to this that would work? The way I have it now would not auto-complete if i started typing `$obj->`, meaning I (or a team member) needs to reference the top of the template to find each available property.

I was considering extending the Template class for each template type, but that seems like unnecessary overhead since I might only add a string and an array per page, and to create a separate class for every template, partial template, and combination of both seems a little silly.

Thank you~

Comment: My advice is not to use magic in most cases it causes more problems that gives advantages

Comment: Thanks, Robert. Would you suggest a class per template type, then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. DocBlocks document classes, not instances.

Saying that, PHPDocumentor has number of class-level annotation tags to expose some of the magic:

- [@property](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html)
- [@property-read](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property-read.html)
- [@property-write](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property-write.html)
- [@method](http://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/method.html)

But it wouldn't work for properties/methods dynamically added at runtime since properties differ between instances.

Comment: Thank you, that answers that, then. Yes I've been using `@property` extensively on our ORM objects, I was just hoping there would be an equivalent for dynamically assigned object keys. Thanks!

Comment: None of your links work now (404). Shame people don't put redirects in when they move pages

Comment: @James 7 years is a long time. phpdoc evolved, php itself changed dramatically towards more typed language. Deprecation of dynamic properties was voted "yes" 50 vs "no" 25 https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_dynamic_properties Yet, you can find the list of currently supported  phpdoc annotations at https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/

Comment: I was just letting you know your links are 404, nothing more :)